# Multipeer connectivity sometimes doesn't send invitations

Tags: ios, io, multipeer-connectivity

Some of us know that the framework multipeer conectivity is a problematic framework, which has some bugs. In my case it was not different, I walked realizing that sometimes when I try to connect with other devices I run into the following problems

> 1) I see the same duplicate devices more than 2 times.
>
> 2) Sometimes when I send an invitation to connect with another device,
>   the call does not reach it! (but most often arrives)

I believe this not to be a problem with my code, as who is responsible for opening the view to display the device list for us to connect is the `MCBrowserViewController`.

In my case, I am testing the exchange of information between a **iphone4s** and my **simulator (iphone4s)**, I do not know if this is what might be giving the problem, what you guys think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get desperate over a bug, you should eliminate the simulator, since it is added complication.  However I have had reasonable success using it.  And rebooting devices (both the host of the simulator and the real device) sometimes has helped with strange MPC behavior after hours of testing different versions of my MPC app.  Finally, be sure to handle MPC data on the main queue as noted in the docs.  Unless you post example code, you only get opinions.